# Is there an RSS reader app that can download full articles instead of abstracts?

Tags: applications, rss, google

One of the main blogs I'm reading has recently transitioned from publishing the full posts in its RSS feed, to publishing just the first few sentences with a "read more" link. This drastically slows me down when reading, as it requires an extra tap and a good number of seconds to load the full, heavy web page instead of the previously light article.

Is there any app that can automatically fetch the full articles from a blog when reading the feed, or - better yet - store all of them in advance so that it can be read offline?

Answer (score 1):

Edit- Newsflow does exactly this with the ability to save article to pocket for offline reading

Also this can be done with Feedly with a simple tweak. Adding a user script called 'full feed' that you can plugin with tampermonkey or stylish that expands the entire article inside Feedly. This also can be saved to pocket for offline view.

Comment: It seems that Feedly was not mentioned in the question. Are you assuming that the OP is having the problem described while using this app?

Comment: He asked for a recommendation for an app that provides the entire feed without having to leave the app to the browser to "read more". I provided a specific solution to give him just that.

Comment: After your edit, my previous comment is no longer needed. Thanks for improving your answer!

Answer (score 0):

[Readkit](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/readkit/id588726889?l=en&mt=12) for Mac has the ability to fetch the whole article via [Readability](https://www.readability.com). [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/ios/) for iOS does the same.

Comment: Seems like Readability only handles one article at a time, when I specifically enter its URL... I'm looking for an automatic solution to pre-fetch all posts in a blog. (E.g. from the past 30 days)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an app, but I've had good luck using [Full-Text RSS](http://fivefilters.org/content-only/), which is a site that can convert most RSS feeds into full text. You can either host it yourself or use their hosted version.